# How to check a string using AND or OR logic with NSCharacterSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nscharacterset

I am using Zxing library to scan the Barcodes. The result is stored in an NSString. Here I am looking into two cases:

***Case:'semicolon'***   :   If the result string contains semicolon character....then store it in     Semicolon Array

```
myWords_semicolon = [_myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";,;;"]
                            ];
       //here myWords_semicolon is a NSArray
```

***Case: 'pipe'*** : If the result string contains pipe character...then store it in a pipe array.

```
myWords_pipe = [_myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"|,||"]
           ];
```

What I tried to do is, if the result string contains semicolon......go to case :'semicolon' ......if the result contains pipe go to case: 'pipe'. I used this to do that but couldn't get the right solution.

```
if ([_myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";,;;"]].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"This string doesnt contain semicolon characters");
        myWords=myWords_pipe;

    }

    if ([_myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"|,||"]].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"This string doesnt contain pipe characters");


        myWords=myWords_semicolon;
    }
```

Here in this case....only semicolon is case is working,even though I scan pipe case ,the scanner is unable to recognize the pipe case.. Is there any other way to use && or || logic here?

Comment: What do your input strings look like? Do you understand that `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";,;;"]` creates a character set whose members are a semicolon `;` and a comma `,`? Doubling the semicolon at the end of the string has no effect.

Comment: Can a string contain both `;` and `|`? What should happen in that case?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you use `characterSetWithCharactersInString` like that.  How is ";,;;" different from ";,"?

Comment: Also, note that there are several different characters that look like the "pipe" character.  Are you sure your source strings are using 0x7C and not some "national" character?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  no, my string is sanitized to have either semicolon or pipe

Comment: my string input looks like this 123||sdsdsd||2323,4556||sdsd||1212|   or 123;asdasd;;1212;;1212,12,12;;sdsd;

Comment: @HOtLicks ---- ";," looks for ; and , and ";,;;" looks for ; and , and ;;. Here i used ";,;;" to recognize two semicolons that present side by side!!!

Comment: No, that's not how character set works.

Comment: Ummm....may be not....but i used the same line of code to differentiate strings by looking at ;    ,     ;; and it worked!!!

Comment: `";,;;"` is a set of `;` and `,`.  It will work to separate at semicolons so long as there are no spurious commas in the string.

Comment: (And don't keep recreating your character sets.  Create them once and use them where needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that both sets contain commas, and at the same time both strings with pipes and strings with semicolons contain commas. Therefore, only the assignment from the last of the two `if`s is going to have an effect, because both `if`s will "fire".

You should be able to fix this by removing commas and duplicate pipes from your sets. Moreover, you should be able to simplify it further by using `rangeOfString:` method instead of `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`

```
if ([_myString rangeOfString:@";"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"This string contains a semicolon");
    myWords=myWords_semicolon;
}
if ([_myString rangeOfString:@"|"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"This string contains a pipe");
    myWords=myWords_pipe;
}
```